# Laravel: 403 This action is unauthorized

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a problem with authorizing a specific user to only click the button but when i tried to press the button is always say Unathorized even though i already dump and die the authorization which is say is `true` don't know which part of the code is wrong. Here is the code.

**Conversation Policy**

```
    public function update(User $user, Conversation $conversation)
{
    //
    return $conversation->user->is($user);
}
```

**Conversation Controller**

```
 public function store(Reply $reply)
    {
        $this->authorize('update', $reply->conversation);
        $this->conversation->bestreply($reply);
    }
```

**The HTML**

```
@foreach ($conversation->replies as $reply)
        <hr>
            <div>
                <p>{{ $reply->user->name }} said...</p>

                {{ $reply->comment }}

                    @can('update',$conversation)

                        <form action="/best-reply/{{ $reply->id }}" method="post">
                            @csrf

                            <button type="submit">best reply</button>

                        </form>
                    @endcan
            </div>
@continue($loop->last)
@endforeach
```

**Conversation Model**

```
    public function bestreply(Reply $reply)
{
    return $this->best_reply = $reply->id;
    $this->save();
}
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**Reply Model**

```
    public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

**Web Route**

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/conversations', 'ConversationsController@index')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/conversations/{conversation}', 'ConversationsController@show');
Route::post('/best-reply/{reply}', 'ConversationBestReplyController@store');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/payment/create', 'PaymentController@index')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/payment', 'PaymentController@store')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/notifications', 'UserNotificationsController@show')->middleware('auth');
```

**Middle ware**

```
public function middleware($middleware = null)
    {
        if (is_null($middleware)) {
            return (array) ($this->action['middleware'] ?? []);
        }

        if (is_string($middleware)) {
            $middleware = func_get_args();
        }

        $this->action['middleware'] = array_merge(
            (array) ($this->action['middleware'] ?? []), $middleware
        );

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: what about your router and middleware

Comment: Route::post('/best-reply/{reply}', 'ConversationBestReplyController@store')->middleware('auth');

try it

Comment: @ShahadatHossain not working.

Comment: can you try `return $user->id === $conversation->user_id;` in your policy?

Comment: have you registered your policy? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#registering-policies

Comment: @ChristopheHubert yes i already register the policies. the ```return $user->id === $conversation->user_id;``` has a same output.